# No sound, 18.04, Dell Laptop

Tags: sound, soundcard

**lsb_release -d**

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

**uname -r**

5.3.0-42-generic

**alsamixer**

│ Card: HDA NVidia                                               │
│ Chip: Nvidia GPU 80 HDMI/DP
│ Item: S/PDIF

> **cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec**
>
> Codec: Nvidia GPU 80 HDMI/DP

**cat /proc/asound/cards:**

0 [NVidia ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia HDA NVidia at 0xa3080000 irq 17 –

**lsmod | grep snd:**

returned a huge list, including snd_hda_intel

Was the intel chip/card disabled? How can i fix this?

Comment: `cat /proc/asound/cards` please.  and `lsmod | grep snd`

Comment: I t would be nice from you to add this to your question. You can edit it.

Comment: @nobody, I am not involved in this. But the user updated their question.